# How to determine the shortest distance between a point and a circle

Tags: processing

So, I am trying to make these two circles kiss, the unfilled circle is the one being drawn at the mouse cursor and the filled one is fixed at the centre of the canvas. Currently, the circles do not kiss and I'm not quite sure how to approach fixing this. Here is the code, quite simple:

```
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  float r = 50; //radius of circle at the centre
  fill(0);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, r, r); //Target Circle

  //what I am assuming should calculate the radius needed to form the
  //kissing circle from my mouse cursor:
  float d = dist(width/2, height/2, mouseX, mouseY) - r; 

  noFill();
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, d, d); //Drawing of circle, desired to kiss the central one.
}
```

[Current Result When Mouse Cursor Is Close To The Centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXSxD.png)

[Current Result When Mouse Cursor Is Farther From The Centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpoat.png)

Note: In these images, I am looking for the two circles to be touching only by changing the radius of the one with no fill, based off of the distance between them.

In the end, I want to be able to have an array of circle objects and get the distance to the closest point in the space. But that is less related to my issue at the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ellipse function expects the width and height of the ellipse (diameters, not radii).
Just change:

```
ellipse(width/2, height/2, r, r);
```

to

```
ellipse(width/2, height/2, 2 * r, 2 * r);
```

and

```
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, d, d)
```

to

```
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 2*d, 2*d)
```

Comment: Wait what is that part about (0,0) being at top left because that is the case.

Comment: Actually I thought exactly like you, but I didn't know your dist() function was an implementation of the euclidian distance. Let me think some more...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the formula is correct. Are you sure that dist() is the Euclidian distance?

Comment: No, but I've tried implementing manually, at least I think I did it properly.

Comment: Let's wait for another answer than. Seems correct to me. What language is this by the way?

Comment: Mind clarifying what you mean by Euclidean distance as well? Do you mean sqrt(sq(x2-x1)+sq(y2-y1)) . If so I believe the dist() function does that, as the result appears (to the eye) very similar.

Comment: The language is built off of java, but has some of its own libraries to aid in beginner use. Here is the software's website: https://processing.org/.

Comment: Yes. Actually it is sqrt((x2 - x1)² + (y2 - y1)²), which is the distance between two points, as you can prove from pythagorean theorem. Probably dist() does that as you said.

Comment: Not sure if this would help with solving, but the circle is larger the further out the mouse is held as it should (just not large enough) but at some point before it (the mouse) reaches the border of the central circle it reaches a minimum and then starts to grow in size again as the mouse gets closer to the circle. It appears that when the mouse is at the point (width/2, height/2 the corresponding circle has the same radius.

Comment: Found the problem. The third and fourth parameters for the ellipse are actually its width and height. Change ellipse(width/2, height/2, r, r) to ellipse(width/2, height/2, 2*r, 2*r) and ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, d, d) to ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 2*d, 2*d)

Comment: Glad to help :)